# JSF - Disable Individual listShuttle Buttons

Tags: jsf, richfaces

With the Richfaces listShuttle component (http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/tlddoc/rich/listShuttle.html), how would one disable/remove ONLY the 'remove' and 'remove all' buttons? I have seen solutions for disabling 'copy all' and 'remove all', or disabling ALL of the buttons, but that doesn't work because I still want the 'copy' buttons to work. What should I do?